# XPages:Display Email content with inline Images

Tags: java, xpages, mime-types, lotus-domino, multipart

I am working on an application that display email content from MIMEEntity, however, i notice when there is inline images in the email, it replace the image with image placeholder  [image]

and when ever there is an empty email content with pdf attachement, i get some string like:

```
%PDF-1.3
%ÔÒ¤Ë
%RSTXPDF3 Parameters: ERSXh
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /FontDescriptor
/Ascent 720
/CapHeight 660
/Descent -270
/Flags 32
/FontBBox [-177 -269 1123 866]
/FontName /Helvetica
/ItalicAngle 0
/StemV 105
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
/WinAnsiEncoding
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
%Devtype PDF1     Font HELVE    normal Lang DE
/Type /Font
/Subtype /Type1
/BaseFont /Helvetica
/Name /F001
/Encoding 3 0 R
/FirstChar 32
/LastChar 255
%Charwidth values from PDF1 HELVE 080 normal
/Widths
[ 278 275 356 556 556 888 669 225 331 331 388 581 275 331 275 275 556 556 556 556 556 556 556 556 556 556 275 275 581 581 581 556 1013 669 669 725 725 669 613 775 725 275 500 669 556 831 725 775 669 775 725 669 613 725 669 944 669 669 613 275 275 275 469
 556 225 556 556 500 556 556 275 556 556 225 225 500 225 831 556 556 556 556 331 500 275 556 500 725 500 500 500 331 263 331 581 0 556 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 331 556 556 556 556 263 556 331 738 369 556 581 0 738
 331 331 581 331 331 331 500 538 275 331 331 363 556 831 831 831 613 669 669 669 669 669 669 1000 725 669 669 669 669 275 275 275 275 725 725 775 775 775 775 775 581 775 725 725 725 725 669 669 613 556 556 556 556 556 556 888 500 556 556 556 556 275 275
 275 275 556 556 556 556 556 556 556 581 613 556 556 556 556 500 556 500]
/FontDescriptor 2 0 R
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Type /FontDescriptor
/Ascent 720...
```

Below is my code:

```
public static String getEmailContent(MIMEEntity mime) throws NotesException {
        String text = null;
        String html = null;
        if (mime != null) {
            if ("multipart".equalsIgnoreCase(mime.getContentType())) {
                MIMEEntity child = mime.getFirstChildEntity();
                while (child != null) {
                    String mimeType = child.getContentType() + "/" + child.getContentSubType();
                    child.decodeContent();
                    String contentDecoded = child.getContentAsText();
                    if ("text/html".equals(mimeType)) {
                        if (html == null) {                         
                            html = contentDecoded;                      
                        }
                    } else if ("text/plain".equals(mimeType)) {
                        if (text == null) {
                            text = "<pre>" + contentDecoded + "</pre>";
                        }
                    }
                    // get next  Child-Element 
                    MIMEEntity tmpChild = child.getFirstChildEntity();
                    if (tmpChild == null) {
                        tmpChild = child.getNextSibling();
                        if (tmpChild == null) {
                            tmpChild = child.getParentEntity();
                            if (tmpChild != null) 
                                tmpChild = tmpChild.getNextSibling();                       }
                    }
                    child = tmpChild;
                }
            } else if ("text".equalsIgnoreCase(mime.getContentType())) {
                String subType = mime.getContentSubType();
                mime.decodeContent();
                String contentDecoded = mime.getContentAsText();
                if ("html".equalsIgnoreCase(subType)) {
                    if (html == null) {
                        html = contentDecoded;
                    }
                } else if ("plain".equalsIgnoreCase(mime.getContentSubType())) {
                    if (text == null) {
                        text = "<pre>" + contentDecoded + "</pre>";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                mime.decodeContent();
                text = "<pre>" + mime.getContentAsText() + "</pre>";
            }
        }
        if (html != null) {

            return html;
        } else {

            return text;
        }
    }
```

I dont know what i am doing wrong, i need some help

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty deep rabbit hole, I think. If you want to display images derived from walking the MIME tree, you'll be on the hook to extract the referenced attachments by CID and filling them in to the original HTML, either as `data` URIs or as references to another script that will serve up the images.

You may be best off making use of IBM's `DominoDocument` class. If you're using a `xp:dominoDocument` data source to start with, you're all set; otherwise, you can use the `DominoDocument.wrap` method to wrap it manually (see [the Javadoc](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/DesignerAPIs/com/ibm/xsp/model/domino/wrapped/DominoDocument.html)). Once you have that, I believe you can use `getValue("someRtField").toString()` to get a useful HTML representation regardless of the original format (CD or MIME), which will use IBM's servlets to display embedded images.

I think you'll still lose attachment references, but you could either use a `xp:fileDownload` control (if the goal is presentation in an XPage) or `getAttachmentList("someRtField")` on the `DominoDocument` object.